# EJS conditional inside loop

Tags: javascript, ejs

The 'quote' variable, containing an array of characters (letters and hyphens), is passed to an ejs template from a node server.  I want to distinguish letters from hyphens.

This doesn't work, as the error message display " Unexpected identifier 'letter' ..."  (Without the if statement, ejs recognizes the "<%= letter %>" construct).

```
<% quote.forEach(letter => { %>
    <% if letter == "-"> { %>
        <span class="quote-letter hyphen">
    <% } else %>
        <span class="quote-letter">
    <% } %>
    <%= letter %>
    </span>
<% }) %>
```

I have also tried this, but it doesn't work either:

```
<% quote.forEach(letter => { %>
    <% if %><%= letter %><% == "-"> { %>
        <span class="quote-letter hyphen">
    <% } else %>
        <span class="quote-letter">
    <% } %>
    <%= letter %>
    </span>
<% }) %>
```

I haven't found any examples of an ejs template where the iteration variable is used in a conditional statement.

I would very much appreciate it if someone can provide a workaround or what I'm doing wrong.  Thanks.

Comment: what does this look like after being rendered?

Comment: This just looks like a series of typos resulting in syntax errors.  You forgot the parentheses around the `if` condition, forgot some curly braces, included a random `>` in the `if` condition, etc.  The fact that the `if` is within a loop doesn't fundamentally change the JavaScript syntax of how `if`s and loops are structured.

Comment: Thanks, David.  I realized that soon after posting.  Appreciate your help.